# WiFi drops out a few seconds after a reboot (issues with upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10

I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 and am facing a number of issues, primary among them being inability to connect to the WiFi. When the machine boots up initially, it is able to connect to WiFi but gets disconnected after a few seconds and stubbornly refuses to connect again. My `dmesg` output is filled with error messages of the form:-

```
[  544.079940] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Dropping frame due to full tx queue 0
[  545.264465] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
[  545.424537] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
```

The entire `dmesg` output can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/m84VGdNc)

I'm using an Ralink Corp RT 3290 Wireless card [1814:3290]. The wireless issue is the primary issue since once I have internet access I can use my own computer to report issues online.

**EDIT:**
As of now I have switched to the older Linux 3.8 kernel to deal with this issue. However, even then some of my other issues persist. You can have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370276/windows-becoming-unresposive-on-upgrade-to-13-10-from-13-04) to see if they have any bearing on this question or not.

Comment: You should edit your question so it deals just with the wireless issue then create a new question for the unresponsiveness of windows.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion...Will do so.

Comment: This is a bug in the kernel. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1239459 there is a patch at the above link as well.